# AND and IN operator in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to achieve the following sql in elastic search:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 = "x1" AND id2 ="relationship" AND products IN ("prod1","prod2") AND id3 = "food"
```

Products can have one value or multiple values. It will be parameterized.

How can I achieve this in Elasticsearch query.

I tried the following but facing error:

```
GET /indexname/seaach
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id1": "x1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "id2": "relationship"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Products": ["prod1","prod2"]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "id3": "food"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id1": "x1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "id2": "relationship"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "products": [
              "prod1",
              "prod2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "id3": "food"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```